# Undefined array key 1 using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, warnings, var-dump

Hello i have warning "Undefined array key 1". I var_dumped array and this is the result. Id like to ask you how can i fix it pls? I tried array_values function but nothing much happened. Im using PHP

```
array(0) { } 
array(1) { [1]=> array(2) { ["sum"]=> int(26140) ["count"]=> int(1) } } 
array(1) { [1]=> array(2) { ["sum"]=> int(52365) ["count"]=> int(2) } } 
array(1) { [1]=> array(2) { ["sum"]=> int(78510) ["count"]=> int(3) } }
```

---

Adding more code. The warning is for last 2 rows

```
$array_months = array();

  foreach($array as $value) {
    if ($value == null) {
      continue;
    }
    $parts = explode('|', $value);
    $datum = explode ('.', $parts[0]);
    $month_int = (int) $datum[1];
    $value_thousand = str_replace (',', '',$parts[1]);
    $value_int = (int) $value_thousand;
    unset($array_months[0]);
    var_dump($array_months);
    $array_months[$month_int]["sum"] = ($array_months[$month_int]["sum"] + $value_int);
    $array_months[$month_int]["count"] = $array_months[$month_int]["count"]+1;
  }
```

Comment: Please share more details. Share a code where you try to get index 1 of array

Comment: These are 4 different arrays. The first one is empty so any array index will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

During the first iteration of your foreach loop and at the assignment line:

`$array_months[$month_int]["sum"] = ($array_months[$month_int]["sum"] + $value_int);`

the right side is evaluated first and at that moment the `$array_months` is empty therefore you cannot read the `$month_int` element of it, because it doesn't exist yet, at any further call its not empty anymore and you don't get the warning multiple times. Since the `$month_int` in your case is equal to 1 the line `unset($array_months[0]);` does nothing at all, if you had `unset($array_months[1]);` or `unset($array_months[$month_int]);` you would get warning at every iteration.

The actuall fix for your specific case is this:

```
// check if there is already element/item for $month_int month present in our array
if(isset($array_months[$month_int])){
    // if so we can read previous data and sum/count them
    $array_months[$month_int]["sum"] = ($array_months[$month_int]["sum"] + $value_int);
    $array_months[$month_int]["count"] = $array_months[$month_int]["count"]+1;
}else{
    // when there isn't any record of current month we have to create the first one
    // (there is nothing to sum or count to yet)
    $array_months[$month_int]["sum"] = $value_int;
    $array_months[$month_int]["count"] = 1;
    // since here is no reading of nonexistent element there is no error now
}
```